# Debugging SSL/TLS Connections in Android

Tags: android, security, debugging, ssl, handshake

Can any one guide me for how to debug SSL/TLS Connections all handshake process.
like:

1. How key generation takes place (Random number , asymmetric key).
2. How to handshake process wrap and unwrap socket channel, and get converted with proper decryption.
3. How to enable debugging log in android for SSL/TLS socket.

According to [Debugging SSL/TLS Connections](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/ReadDebug.html), Java uses `java -Djavax.net.debug=all MyApp sor ssl debuging`.

Comment: Do you want to monitor socket level data? Or do you only want to debug http level data. If you need the latter, then you can simply user an http debugging tool such as Charles or Fiddler.

Comment: Thanks Ruchira, Actually want to identify how java decides to encrypt and decrypt logic for ssl socket. Also how it is enabled . I walk through above link but still not able to debug with source code . For packate analysis i use wireshark but it is not my need.

Comment: Hi Nilesh,
Usually any OS comes with an inbuilt set of functions which handles all the complicated details regarding the establishment of a SSL connection.

As you know, there is a complex chain of events which includes exchanging of certificates, validation of the certificates, initiation and exchange of keys which will ultimately establish a secure SSL connection.

These OS layer libraries handle them in such a manner that we can focus on our logic by simply changing the URL to "https" instead of "http".

As in your case, I really don't have an idea on how to view such keys!

Comment: I know that OS level libraries are doing it. But On java in above link I found that SSLEngin doing it . But unable to identify the handshaking process. step by step. I am android developer and I know that android using Boring ssl /Openssl for this purpose .

Comment: But not able to exact tracing of classes for handshaking purpose , keys, cipher exchanging. Can you please suggest me somee classes where I can find this certificate and keys exchange are starting or validating?. I know it is much vast as there are number of algorithm , cipher there but little start of handshaking can help me much . I debug SSLSocketfactory , SSLEngin, but didn't find it.

Comment: Hi Nilesh, I'm not sure if this answers your questions. But, have a look at the "startHandshake()" method of this file.
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/conscrypt/+/f087968/src/main/java/org/conscrypt/OpenSSLSocketImpl.java

Comment: Thanks I was looking there , I think NativeCrypto.SSL_do_handshake do most of task.

Comment: Hey Ruchira , Can we use this  "java -Djavax.net.debug=all " in android?

Comment: Hi Nilesh, I'm not sure on that really.

Comment: k ... thanks ..you really helped me